# MySql and SQL Server backup with code

Tags: c++, mysql, sql-server

I try to back up from MySQL with codes. Is it possible?

If it will possible, I could use this code getting backup from SQL Server.

Thank a lot.

Comment: Please add some more information, e.g. what platform you are on.

Comment: I use C++ and QT and studio 2008.

I have to write a program back up MySql and SqlServer. I write a function which get back up from MySql and SqlServer.
I research it. MySql backup file .sql extension. MSSql is .bak extension. and When I restore it, this make a problem.

Comment: what is the core issue here. Do you want to exchange data between mySQL and SQL server?

Comment: Yes. I try to a program run without database platform.
I try to write my sql command according to it. I did it. But when I come getting back up I cant do it. Do you know any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the command-line tool [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).

```
mysqldump -u username -ppassword -h hostname databasename > filename.sql
```

It can create dumps from local or remote databases.

It is a part of the mySQL installation package (in the `/bin` directory)

Comment: I dont wantto back up on command line. I have to back up with code.

Comment: @john That is possible, but it's *quite* complex to achieve as you have to replicate what the dump tool does. You're in for quite a lot of work. Think twice whether that is the perfect solution to your problem.